# How can I toggle smartcase in Vim?

Tags: vim

I love `smartcase`, but there are times that I'd like to turn it off and search for just lowercase.  Is there a builtin that will toggle smartcase, or do I need to write a function to toggle it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you add a bang after the option name in the `set` command, like this:

```
:set smartcase!
```

...it will *toggle* the option. You can create a key mapping to do this:

```
:map \s :set smartcase!<CR>
```

`<CR>` stands for carriage return. It represents the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Now just press <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and it toggles.

I usually write the mapping to also show in the bottom line whether the option is on or off, like this:

```
:map \s :set smartcase!<CR>:set smartcase?<CR>
```

Comment: Prefer <cr>, it's much simplier to maintain, and explain, than ^M.

Comment: @Luc: I wasn't sure you could use that, and I didn't have vim handy to try, so I went with what I knew for sure. Will edit.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to toggle if off completely, just do

```
:set nosmartcase
```

But if you want to toggle the mode of one-two searches, use special symbols in your search patterns:

- `\c` makes the pattern ignore case, for example: `/iGnOrEcAsE\c` (matches "ignorecase");
- `\C` makes the pattern match case, for example: `/matchcase\C` (doesn't march "MatchCase").